# Multiple Upload and Image names

Tags: php

I have a multiple upload form, that renames images after upload:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['images']['name']); $i++) {
$ext= end(explode(".",  $_FILES['images']['name'][$i]));
$name =  rand(1111111,9999999).'.'.$ext; 
}
```

With `print_r($name)` the output is a string `image1.jpgimage2.jpgimage3.jpg`.
Why the output is a string? How can I give an array? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do not put a count() in the condition part of a for loop. PHP Internals does not cache this value and will perform a 'recount' of your array every time it loops. Put the count in a $count variable before your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$name[] = rand(1111111,9999999).'.'.$ext;
```

will do the trick

Bonus:

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['images']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: @fabric;
Now the output is `Array
(
    [0] => 9292066.jpg
)

Array
(
    [0] => 9292066.jpg
    [1] => 5713362.jpg
)

Array
(
    [0] => 9292066.jpg
    [1] => 5713362.jpg
    [2] => 4854885.jpg
)`

Comment: Isn't that you are looking for?

Comment: I want somthing like this :Array ( [0] => 9292066.jpg ) Array ([1] => 5713362.jpg ) Array ([2] => 4854885.jpg ).
Because I want to save image name in database (I dont know If it is a right way)

Comment: Im sorry:( In third section of array there is "Array ( [0] => 9292066.jpg [1] => 5713362.jpg [2] => 4854885.jpg"
I want Only the [2] => 4854885.jpg section.

Comment: Sorry, i think i don't understand you. $_FILES['images']['name'] is an array, right? If you loop through these images and store their names in an array, my solution must be fine i think.